# What does io.on do besides the connection event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, socket.io

I am using Socket.IO. On the server side is `IO.on('connection',(socket)=>{...})` the only `IO . on` event? I am trying for something like `IO.on('event',(socket,args)=>{...})`, but it's not working. Can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO, erkus!

> What does io.on do besides the connection event?

In the server context, `io` should refer to the `Server` object. Its available APIs are listed here:
https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#Server

> is `IO.on('connection',(socket)=>{...})` the only  `IO.on` event?

As fair as the documented APIs, yes.

> I am trying for something like `IO.on('event',(socket,args)=>{...})`, but it's not working. Can anybody tell me why?

Because you should listen to your `'event'` on the [`Socket`](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#Socket) object, instead:

e.g.

```js
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('event', function(args){
    console.log('message: ' + args);
  });
});
```

I believe you would benefit from looking at the chat demo:
https://socket.io/get-started/chat/